# Octave won't work when I want to multiply big matrices (or just work once in a while)

Tags: matrix, octave, ubuntu-20.04

EDIT : I simply try this and it doesn't work either :

```
A=rand(5000,401)*rand(401,25);
```

[image]

Every line executed itself instantanely except for the last one......

Yesterday I wrote some code multiplying matrices in octave (which worked perfectly fine) and today the same code won't work, and after some tests I think the problem is about "big" matrices multiplications and I cannot find any fix...

[image: Some code]

[image]

on the output, test 3 is never displayed...

[image]

my htop during the execution...

I am on Ubuntu 20, and Octave 5.2.0

Comment: was it working with exact same code and exact same parameters and is not working now? or any of them changed between runs?

Comment: It may be worth creating a testcase and opening a bug in the octave bug tracker. However, some work would be useful first. Does this happen consistently for matrices of that size, or does your specific workspace / environment matter? If you repeat this process with successively big matrices, can you plot a trend that suggests this would take this long, or is the delay surprising? How big is 'big'? How long is 'never'? Are any optimizations turned on that might interfere? What are your computer's specs / RAM? How much memory would the inputs and the result be expected to take?

Comment: Also, it's worth considering what you expect the computer to do. E.g. a 10,000 x 10,000 matrix on a machine with a double of 8 bytes takes 800Mb. Multiplying (and storing the result) of such an operation would take about 2.4Gb of working memory for this operation alone. On my machine, multiplying 1,000x1,000 took 1 second, 5,000x5,000 took 3 minutes, and 8,000x8,000 took 12 minutes. I suspect 10,000x10,000 will take about an hour, so I didn't run it. In general, when dealing with "big data" like this, it's worth trying different strategies, like block processing.

Comment: You may even find that, despite the usual advice about avoiding for loops in favour of vectorising, when dealing with big data, due to the memory considerations involved and difficulty in performing memory allocations efficiently, it's often faster to just fall back to performing a for loop over several smaller operations and collecting the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
my spec : i5 10th gen with 8 gb of ram
my datas are some basic int (0-255 from an exercice of coursera machine learning so it is optimized)
I'm wprking on Ubuntu in dual boot,
and when my code worked fine with this database, the result took aproximately 1 second to be computed.
I try to let it compute now for more than 10 mn ?? (Also I uninstall and re install octave just to be sure)

Comment: I edited my post for clarification. 
Also, isn't it strange that only one core is used every time by octave ? (souldn't it parallelized the matrice's multiplication ? )

Comment: are you using code that would perform the parallelization? parallel functions aren't the default. what are your times for each of the steps leading up to the big one, like Tasos's comment?

Comment: @Julie96 just so you know, one only gets a notification if someone replies to their question /answer, otherwise if you wanted me to get a notification you should have tagged me in your comment (e.g. start writing @t and press tab to autocomplete). No, single core is the norm, parallelisation is not performed unless you specifically call a parallel implementation (this is true for all languages). But, you're right, I would have expected `A=rand(5000,401)*rand(401,25);` to be relatively instantaneous too, it's not that big a calculation ...